# How to shift bars in bar graph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, graphs, bar-chart, ticks

I have plotted the following  figure: [image: graph]

I would like to **shift the green bars to the right**, so they become adjacent on the right of the blue bars. Yet the green and blue bars have the same vertical axis, so I don't know how to shift only the green bars (the blue bars are already shifted, as seen from line 33, indicated with `%<-----`).

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Code of the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        symbolic x coords={Carreau,Carreau-Yasuda,Casson,Cross,Gen. power-law,Power-law,Newtonian},
        x tick label style={rotate=45},
        bar width=0.5cm, bar shift=-0.285cm,
        xtick=data,
        axis y line*=left,
        ylabel={\textit{C\textsubscript{D}}}, ymin=0.0422, ymax=0.0447,
        ytick={0.0425, 0.0430, 0.0435, 0.0440, 0.0445},
        xlabel={},
        width=12cm, height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left}
        ]
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red] coordinates {
            (Carreau,0.043242) (Carreau-Yasuda,0.043149) (Casson,0.042620) (Cross,0.043006) (Gen. power-law,0.044280) (Power-law,0.043266) (Newtonian,0.042715)
          }; \label{plot_CD}
      \end{axis}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        symbolic x coords={Carreau,Carreau-Yasuda,Casson,Cross,Gen. power-law,Power-law,Newtonian},
        xticklabels={ , , , , , , },
        x tick label style={rotate=45},
        bar width=0.5cm, bar shift=0.25cm, %<-----
        xtick=data,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={\textit{$\Delta$p}, 10$\cdot$\textit{$\uptau$\textsubscript{wall}} [Pa]}, ymin=40, ymax=140,
        ytick={50, 70, 90, 110, 130},
        width=12cm, height=6cm,
        legend cell align={left}
        ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_CD}\addlegendentry{\textit{C\textsubscript{D}}},
        \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (Carreau,84.30) (Carreau-Yasuda,80.58) (Casson,56.03) (Cross,74.95) (Gen. power-law,129.74) (Power-law,84.45) (Newtonian,72.1)
          };  \label{plot_delta_p} \addlegendentry{\textit{$\Delta$p} [Pa]}
        \addplot[draw=green,fill=green] coordinates {
            (Carreau,81.4942) (Carreau-Yasuda,79.5077) (Casson,44.9415) (Cross,77.7879) (Gen. power-law,77.8555) (Power-law,76.9145) (Newtonian,65.2255)
          };  \label{plot_tau_wall_times_10} \addlegendentry{10$\cdot$\textit{$\uptau$\textsubscript{wall}} [Pa]}
        \legend{\textit{C\textsubscript{D}}, \textit{$\Delta$p} [Pa], 10$\cdot$\textit{$\uptau$\textsubscript{wall}} [Pa]}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some minor changes to your code, adding the `bar shift`to each plot, with a size  slightly larger than the `bar width`, with the blue bar at the center.

Also moved the  x-axis labels  closer to the ticks.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={Carreau,Carreau-Yasuda,Casson,Cross,Gen. power-law,Power-law,Newtonian},
            x tick label style={xshift=-15pt, yshift=5pt, rotate=45}, % changed <<<<<<<<
            bar width=0.35cm, % changed <<<<<<<<
            xtick=data,
            axis y line*=left,
            ylabel={\textit{C\textsubscript{D}}}, ymin=0.0422, ymax=0.0447,
            ytick={0.0425, 0.0430, 0.0435, 0.0440, 0.0445},
            xlabel={},
            width=12cm, height=6cm,
            legend cell align={left}
            ]
            \addplot[draw=red,fill=red, bar shift=-0.4cm] coordinates { % changed <<<<<<<<
            (Carreau,0.043242) (Carreau-Yasuda,0.043149) (Casson,0.042620) (Cross,0.043006) (Gen. power-law,0.044280) (Power-law,0.043266) (Newtonian,0.042715)
            }; \label{plot_CD}
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={Carreau,Carreau-Yasuda,Casson,Cross,Gen. power-law,Power-law,Newtonian},
            xticklabels={ , , , , , , },
            x tick label style={rotate=45},
            bar width=0.35cm, % changed <<<<<<<<
            xtick=data,
            axis y line*=right,
            ylabel={\textit{$\Delta$p}, 10$\cdot$\textit{$\uptau$\textsubscript{wall}} [Pa]}, ymin=40, ymax=140,
            ytick={50, 70, 90, 110, 130},
            width=12cm, height=6cm,
            legend cell align={left}
            ]
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_CD}\addlegendentry{\textit{C\textsubscript{D}}};                
                \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue,  bar shift=0.0cm,] coordinates { % changed <<<<<<<<
                (Carreau,84.30) (Carreau-Yasuda,80.58) (Casson,56.03) (Cross,74.95) (Gen. power-law,129.74) (Power-law,84.45) (Newtonian,72.1)
            };  \label{plot_delta_p} \addlegendentry{\textit{$\Delta$p} [Pa]}               
            \addplot[draw=green,fill=green, bar shift=0.4cm,] coordinates { % changed <<<<<<<<
                (Carreau,81.4942) (Carreau-Yasuda,79.5077) (Casson,44.9415) (Cross,77.7879) (Gen. power-law,77.8555) (Power-law,76.9145) (Newtonian,65.2255)
            };  \label{plot_tau_wall_times_10} \addlegendentry{10$\cdot$\textit{$\uptau$\textsubscript{wall}} [Pa]}                 
        
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```